# Mikrotik Hotspot Performance Degradation: So Slow Hotspot Unusable

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, hotspot, latency, mikrotik-routeros

### FAULT:

Hotspot created with Mikrotik's "***ip*** > ***Hotspot***" wizard is so painfully slow that it is unusable

Googling "***mikrotik hotspot slow***" returned a gazillion results, none of which resolved this fault.

I checked queues, DNS, proxy and firewall rules created by the Mikrotik "***wizard***"- which *appeared* to provide the correct connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mikrotik's automated Hotspot "***wizard***" created the fault: it inserts its rules ABOVE the one allowing ***related,established*** connections in the **FORWARD** chain.

### RESOLUTION:

Moving the ***related,established*** rule to the top of the **FORWARD** chain successfully resolves this fault, restoring normal web browsing performance.

Hopefully long-suffering Mikrotik users will find this answer and save themselves reading numerous posts which lead them in the wrong direction...

Comment: Good on you for figuring out the answer.  Mikrotik products are good.  Mikrotik *wizards* are not always the brightest.

Comment: @JoelAZ  I used their routers with Ubiquiti AirFibers to configure a WAN that spanned the Northern half of Nigeria a few years ago.  They are good stuff. Agreed, nobody gets it right all the time, but Mikrotik do some really brilliant kit.